# program to find execution time of addition in c

Tags: c

I want to find execution time of addition instruction in C. I know how to find using for loop but i don't want to use any loop. I want to find for a single instruction. I have written this code.

```
void main()
{
    int a=34,b=56,c,i;
    clock_t start,end;
    double exectime;

    start=clock();
    c=a+b;
    end=clock();

    exectime=(double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\nExecution Time= %f \n",exectime);
}
```

But the output is coming 0. I have also tried converting in nanoseconds,but still not working.

Comment: Its better to look into dis-assembly for addition statement,find out number of clocks required for instruction.Calculate time based on operating frequency of processor.

Comment: A tip: Always use `int main()` and a matching `return` statement.

Comment: @SouravGhosh There is no effect in using int main()

Comment: @Vagish Number of clocks required is also coming zero.

Comment: @RachnaShriwas There might be _no effect_ but what I suggested is the C standard. Have a look into chapter 5.1.2.2.1 in `C11` standard.

Comment: What is CLOCKS_PER_SEC ?

Comment: @Vagish clock() returns the CPU clock cycles. To change it in seconds we need to divide by CLOCKS_PER_SEC.

Comment: He means what is the value of CLOCKS_PER_SEC

Comment: What is actual value of CLOCKS_PER_SEC ? AND What is operating frequency     of your CPU?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I agree with you Sir. But it's not solving the problem.

Comment: @RachnaShriwas It won't solve your problem, that's why i mentioned it as a _tip_, not an _answer_. :-)

Comment: Maybe the frequency is more that's why i'm getting answer 0.

Comment: But what can be the alternative to find time of a single instruction ?

Comment: Using function calls that execute thousands of instructions in an attempt to time what is, probably, a register-register add is just not sane.

Comment: You should realize that computers are really fast at doing arithmetic.

Comment: This is like trying to microwave a curry readymeal using a galactic core, or a binary pulsar system.

Comment: None of the non-clock, non-output code needs to run. There's no need to add anything. Except for the measurements, the program does *nothing*. It is effectively measuring how long it takes to do nothing. Even if you had proper granularity and a noise-free environment, it would be measuring the wrong things, i.e., nothing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I had a Chicken Jalfrezi readymeal last night, but I used cosmic microwave background radiation.

Comment: @MartinJames: Feeling a little squirmy this morning?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit kinda irritated in places, yes, or maybe irradiated.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - maybe all optimization is off?

Comment: Apart from using the Time Stamp Counter as commented, any other measurement system used for an operation so quick, is going to give a result of either 0 or 1 in the units of its granularity, neither of which will be correct.

Comment: @MartinJames that's just a slower way of doing nothing. :P

Answer (score 6):

The short answer for why your code isn't working is that your program executes too quickly. `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is usually defined so that each tick is equal to one microsecond (`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` equals 1 million) - a single addition operation takes *far* less than that. In fact, on my machine I had to execute several million instructions before I was able to get a non-zero measurement.

There's no standard way in C to measure the length of a single add instruction. You can use the [rdtsc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) instruction in modern x86 processors to measure CPU clock cycles, though even then precision is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

**Its very tough to get some clocks needed for some instructions. Because it depends upon a lot of factors as CPU clock Frequency, No of CPU cores, Processor Architecture(How memory cache are assigned), instruction scheduling, and branch prediction,instructions executed before your measured instruction(s), etc.**

If you need to measure very short time intervals or you need extremely high precision in your figures,you can resort to platform-dependent resources.

Every CPU manufacturers include some clock counters(REGISTERS) and these are incremented for every lapsed clock on that CPU core. So you can access these REGISTER(s) if your CPU allowed(Manufacturer dependent) and calculate much more precise execution time.
Example: The most renowned counter register is the TSC (timestamp counter), introduced in x86 processors with the Pentium and present in all CPU designs ever since—including the x86_64 platform. It is a 64-bit register that counts CPU clock cycles; it can be read from both kernel space and user space.

```
<asm/msr.h>
unsigned long start, stop;
rdtscl(start); 
//Your measured code here
rdtscl(stop);
printk("Time Taken: %li\n", stop- start);
```

*Even its also not perfect because there are some clock cycles lapsed in reading these registers, but anyhow we can't remove it.*

For more info you can see link provided by @Daniel. and http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-1

Answer (score -3):

Instead Use `gettimeofday()`.

`clock()` time granularity is not enough probably.

Comment: No, `clock()` measures CPU time of this process, which is what you want. Wall time is not what you want to measure.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit are you sure you read the answer right? punctuation and everything??? It says to use gettimeofday() and not clock() because the granularity is not good enough in the case of time(). I see nothing wrong with that

Comment: @Pandrei If you use `gettimeofday()` instead of `clock()`, the output can be something as silly as "Execution Time= -1.0", for example. `gettimeofday` is just the wrong measurement tool. It's simply not usable for measuring the passage of time: it fails to uphold the basic requirement that subsequent calls return values that are equal or higher than the results of previous calls.

Comment: @Pandrei: I just told you what's wrong with that. Do you understand the difference between time of day, and the execution time of a single process, under a multi-process operating system? "Wall time" and "CPU time" are, in the context of any given process, not _at all_ the same measurement.

Comment: It doesn't matter anyway becasue carbon-14 dating is an inappropriate tool for measuring defrosting time for a curry readymeal.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand that gettimeofday() measures elapsed time which is different to execution time; but it does have e better granularity than clock(), and it is widely used for benchmarking/measuring code execution time. It depends on how accurate you want to be with your measurement.

Comment: @Pandrei: No it's not; that would be ridiculous. If you're benchmarking code using wall time then your benchmarks are _wrong_. Increased granularity (read: the _illusion_ of) does not change that. As for your final remark, he's measuring _one_ operation! So he has to be ridiculously super accurate. None of this is going to work, at all.

Comment: The question is about granularity. And for this particular purpose which is not multi threaded, I think gettimeofday() could be more helpful.